# Calling bean method on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I'm trying to call a method that connects that is on a Bean on a jsp file. 
The method will make a request to a RMI Server and return a string. 
At this point the method is just return a pre-defined string for test.

This is the bean method:

```
public String getListProjects() throws RemoteException {

    this.dataToSend = new Object[2];
    this.dataToSend[1] = 0;

    this.postCard = new ClientRequest("2", this.dataToSend, "tempo");

    try{
      this.postCard = this.connectToRMI.getActualProjects(this.postCard);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Hello";

}
```

And this is the jsp code:

```xml
<h1>Projectos Actuais</h1>

<h2><%

    fundstarter.model.ConnectToRMIBean aux = new       fundstarter.model.ConnectToRMIBean();
    try{
        aux.getListProjects();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    %>
</h2>
```

I'm guiding my self from another code, and the method is called like this. But in my case it's not working, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Is variable connectToRMI defined in jsp? You should sirround with try-catch  and check for errors.

Comment: No, connectToRMI is the name of the bean class. It's not define on jsp

Comment: this.connectToRMI -> this. Implies it's a variable. In which case you simply have a Nullpointer in jsp.

Comment: Sorry, when i do the "this.connectToRMI" is in the bean file, and it's working, because i have other methods that call RMI method with connectToRMI. But in this case the method isn't called

Comment: Or is it the typo getPorjects vs getProjects?

Comment: I have just changed the typo, but it's still not working

Comment: Check with try-catch. Add error to your question. Please.

Comment: I've tried with the try catch and it didn't have any error

Comment: Can you update your post to show change? What do you get inside <h2>?

Comment: I've updated the post, that is the last version of my code. When i run the jsp there is nothing in the <h2>

Comment: Ah. I meant: put try catch *in jsp* to catch the error there.

Comment: did you check how you are calling bean on your jsp page, probable that will be issue.

Comment: Updated the code, still no error. I can see in the RMI that the method is called but, theres still not in the <h2>

Comment: not sure why you are calling bean directly with object, I am using this way
<jsp:useBean id="beanName" class="com.test.BeanName" scope="request" />
....
....
${beanName.Message}

Comment: see my answer -> you're missing to actually output the result into HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting and fixing your latest change on edit with some comments:

```
<h1>Projectos Actuais</h1>

<h2><%
    try{        
      fundstarter.model.ConnectToRMIBean aux = new       fundstarter.model.ConnectToRMIBean();

      //Send result into generated HTML page with out.print!
      out.print(aux.getListProjects());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    %>
</h2>
```

Comment: @GabrielOliveira: Technically It may work, but scriptlets are bad, very bad. If you're using some framework (i.e. Struts2) learn how to do things in a framework way. Check [Andrea's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34175556/1700321).

Comment: I totally agree. This is not the best answer. Just the one that was closest to the code at time of fix.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged this [struts2](/questions/tagged/struts2), assuming the `getListProjects()` is on the Action, in JSP use:

```xml
<s:property value="listProjects" />
```

If instead it is on a bean, declare the bean in the Action, and expose it through a getter:

```java
private MyBean bean;

public MyBean getBean(){ 
    return bean; 
}
```

and in JSP use the *dot notation*:

```xml
<s:property value="bean.listProjects" />
```

P.S: always avoid Scriptlets (`<% %>`), [they're evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1654265).

Answer (score 0):

As per the flow of Struts there should be field in beanclass with same name of getter & setter. For an example if your method name is getListPorjects then in your bean class there should be a private string variable name listprojects.

Also your method will update with following to way to return listprojects.

example:

```
public String getListProjects() throws RemoteException {

    this.dataToSend = new Object[2];
    this.dataToSend[1] = 0;

    this.postCard = new ClientRequest("2", this.dataToSend, "tempo");

    try{
      this.postCard = this.connectToRMI.getActualProjects(this.postCard);
      listprojects = "hello"
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listprojects;

}
```

Calling bean variable should be with ID over the JSP page.

```
<jsp:useBean id="aux" class="com.path.to.ConnectToRMIBean" scope="request" /> 
----
yours stuff
-----

<h1>${aux.listProjects}
```

hope this will help you. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the way <% %> and <%= %> are used in JSP. to print in <% %> tags use

```
<% out.println("Your results"); %>
```

and for <%= %>

```
<%=
   String.valueOf(1+2);
%>
```

Comment: what you mean..??, $ it self work as a scriplet for variable.

Comment: i am referring to what is in question posted. not your code. how will this ever print ?     <%    aux.getListProjects();    %>

Comment: Question was updated, previously code was there to print listProjects is with $ tag.  And however using a object of bean is not correct way to show  any beanclass element.